# "No Data" in pennant pattern strategy back testing

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am a bit of noob when it comes to PineScript, and have been hitting my head against a wall for a few hours trying to figure this out. I am trying to backtest a simple bullish Pennant Pattern strategy for my own learning/experimentation, and I keep getting "no data" in the TradingView strategy testing console.

I have removed almost everything element from my strategy to try to debug the problem, but am getting nowhere. Does anybody see what might be the error here? I assume my conditions are too stringent, but I don't see how that is possible, plus it doesn't even seem to work when I add a simple "if price > { some_value }" statement.

Here is the strategy:

```
//@version=5
strategy("Bullish Pennant strategy", overlay=true)

// Define parameters
ema_period = 50

// Calculate the 50-day EMA of the closing price
ema = ta.ema(close, ema_period)

// Determine if there was a sharp increase in price over earliest 6 bars of our period
sharp_increase = close[14] > close[19]
peak_price = math.max(high[19], high[18], high[17], high[16], high[15], high[14])

// Determine if there was a retracement going down in price over the next 12 bars
downtrend = true
highest_price = peak_price
for i = 13 to 1
    highest_price := math.max(highest_price, high[i])
    if low[i] < ema or (high[i] > high[i+1] and (high[i] > peak_price or high[i] > highest_price))
        downtrend := false
        break

// Determine if there was a solid bullish bar
bullish_bar = close[0] > open[0]

// Generate the buy signal
if sharp_increase and downtrend and bullish_bar
    strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an entry but you don't have an exit. So, you are in a position forever. Use `strategy.exit()` or `strategy.close()` to close your existing position.

[image]